# Using a hotkey to submit an HTML form?

Tags: html, forms, submit, hotkeys

I have a very simple HTML form, only containing a submit button and a textarea.
Is there an easy way to use a hotkey to submit this form, as an alternative to pressing the button?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: @Lehto — it already has a function: inserting a new line in the textarea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Submit buttons can have [accesskeys](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey), but there are [drawbacks](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey#poor). Users would probably be better off just hitting the tab key to focus the submit button, and then pressing enter.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for as the website isn't aimed toward the greater public so the browser difference in handling accesskeys is no problem :-)

Comment: @MojtabaRezaeian — Works in Firefox 64.0 when I test it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the jQuery method for adding a keypress listener to your button (by specifying the ID)... you can also do it on your page by changing "YourID"  to "document" (without quotes, since document is a page element. I know keypress has been mentioned, figured it would be easier for others to have code here, and not have to move elsewhere.

```
$("#YourID").keypress(function (e) {
   var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which); // grabs keycode pressed
   if (code == 13) {  // Code 13 is enter
        searchUPC();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the "keyDown", "keyPress" events if you use a JS library (JQUERY or MOOTOOLS).. you can program your own Ctrl+S to submit.

On JQuery see this http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

On Mootools see this http://mootorial.com/wiki/mootorial/03-native/05-event

Comment: Ctrl+S (in Firefox for Windows at least) usually means "Save this page". Messing with user expectations is usually not a good idea.